# In Laravel, how to give another implementation to the service container when testing?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a Laravel controller where a Random string generator interface gets injected to one of the methods. Then in AppServiceProvider I'm registering an implementation. This works fine.

The controller uses the random string as input to save data to the database. Since it's random, I can't test it (using `MakesHttpRequests`) like so:

```
$this->post('/api/v1/do_things', ['email' => $this->email])
->seeInDatabase('things', ['email' => $this->email, 'random' => 'abc123']);
```

because I don't know what 'abc123' will be when using the actual random generator. So I created another implementation of the Random interface that always returns 'abc123' so I could assert against that.

Question is: **how do I bind to this fake generator at testing time?** I tried to do

```
$this->app->bind('Random', 'TestableRandom');
```

right before the test, but it still uses the actual generator that I register in AppServiceProvider. Any ideas? Am I on the wrong track completely regarding how to test such a thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a couple options:

Use a conditional to bind the implementation:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        if($this->app->runningUnitTests()) {
           $this->app->bind('Random', 'TestableRandom');
        } else {
           $this->app->bind('Random', 'RealRandom');
        }
    }
}
```

Second option is to use a mock in your tests

```
public function test_my_controller () {
    // Create a mock of the Random Interface
    $mock = Mockery::mock(RandomInterface::class);

    // Set our expectation for the methods that should be called
    // and what is supposed to be returned
    $mock->shouldReceive('someMethodName')->once()->andReturn('SomeNonRandomString');

    // Tell laravel to use our mock when someone tries to resolve
    // an instance of our interface
    $this->app->instance(RandomInterface::class, $mock);

    $this->post('/api/v1/do_things', ['email' => $this->email])
         ->seeInDatabase('things', [
             'email' => $this->email, 
             'random' => 'SomeNonRandomString',
         ]);
}
```

If you decide to go with the mock route. Be sure to checkout the mockery documentation:

http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html

Comment: Went with the conditional binding approach for now. Thanks!

Comment: I think the way to go is the second alternative. The first option shouldn't be even considered. It's not only ugly but also must be hard to maintain.

Comment: @Parziphal depends. I use Elasticsearch and I have wrapped the ES calls in a separate class. In the bindings I register a fake indexing class implementation when running tests.

Comment: @Parziphal It really depends. I have a PaymentServiceProvider that returns me the right payment method service depending on the payment_method_id attribute(int) in the order. I've created a TestPaymentMethod service and mapped it to the id -1. This may be a little hacky, but it is a lot cleaner than mocking my PaymentMethod interface on almost all of my integration tests.

Comment: it feels both solutions are bad... you should be able to define your own implementation inside the test

Answer (score 1):

From laracasts

```
class ApiClientTest extends TestCase
{
    use HttpMockTrait;

    private $apiClient;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->setUpHttpMock();

        $this->app->bind(ApiConfigurationInterface::class, FakeApiConfiguration::class);

        $this->apiClient = $this->app->make(ApiClient::class);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function example()
    {
        dd($this->apiClient);
    }
}
```

results

```
App\ApiClient^ {#355
  -apiConfiguration: Tests\FakeApiConfiguration^ {#356}
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/laravel-58-interface-binding-while-running-tests?page=1&replyId=581880